# NameError (uninitialized constant Enumerators::CompactEnumerator)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In one of my projects, i am using Ruby on Rails and trying to store data in my database.
My code for this.

```
Enumerators::CompactEnumerator.new(
        Enumerators::MapEnumerator.new(events) { |event|
          event_info =
            IssueEventInfo.new(
              github_id: event[:id],
              actor:
                Actor.new(
                  github_login: event[:actor][:login]
                ),
              created_at: Time.parse(event[:createdAt])
            )
```

I am getting this error while doing so.

```
NameError (uninitialized constant Enumerators::CompactEnumerator)
```

I have tried everything to understand whats going on but unable to understand.

Comment: check if you have a model with file name `compact_enumerator.rb` and class name `Enumerators ::CompactEnumerator` in your codebase or not. specifically check for spelling mistakes in file or class names.

Comment: Its basically part of a plugin and there is no `compact_enumerator.rb` class in my models folder

Comment: well, in that case, check if you need `require` the gem in the file where you want to use the above class.

Comment: _"Its basically part of a plugin"_ What plugin? How did you install the plugin?